# Unable to convert scala object to spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `scala` object being passed to the `dashBoardInsert` method, and I have crosschecked that I am receiving data through the parameter.

Now I want to convert it to `dataframe`, but I am getting the error below:

```
 def dashBoardInsert(data: TripHistoryData) {

    println("seven..")


     println("data= " + data.asset_id)

   var Seq2=sc.parallelize(Seq(data.service_id,data.asset_id,"odometer", "calculated",data.odometer,new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), data.asset_serial_no))


   import sparkSession.implicits._
val df1 = Seq2.toDF("data.service_id","data.asset_id","odometer", "calculated","data.odometer","new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())","new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())", "data.asset_serial_no"))
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Error:

  value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String with Long <: Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String with Long <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable]
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You create data frame with different types of elements inside.

`Seq(data.service_id,data.asset_id,"odometer", "calculated",data.odometer,new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), data.asset_serial_no)` is `Seq[Any]`, but you need `Seq` with tuple inside of it.

You should write:

```
val tuple = (data.service_id,data.asset_id,"odometer", "calculated",data.odometer,new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), data.asset_serial_no)
val local = Seq(tuple)
var distrebuted = sc.parallelize(localSeq)
val df = distrebuted.toDF("data.service_id","data.asset_id","odometer", "calculated","data.odometer","new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())","new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())", "data.asset_serial_no")
```